# Coursera programming language hw2

Tags: programming-languages, sml

```
fun officiate (clist , mlist , score) =
    let val hlist = []
    in
      let
        fun appendh ([], _, score) = hlist
          | appendh (_, [], score) = hlist 
          | appendh (c :: clist', m :: mlist', score) = 
        case (sum_cards(hlist) > score, m) of
            (true, _) => hlist
          | (false, Draw) => c :: appendh(clist', mlist', score)
          | (false, Discard a) => remove_card(hlist, a, IllegalMove) @ appendh(clist', mlist', score)                            
      in
        score(appendh(clist, mlist, score), score)
      end
    end
```

//val officiate = fn : card list * move list * int -> int

//val score = fn : card list * int -> int

When I use this function， I caught this bug ：

---

- use "hw2.sml";
  [opening hw2.sml]
  hw2.sml:137.6-137.48 Error: operator is not a function [tycon mismatch]
  operator: int
  in expression:
  score (appendh (clist,mlist,score),score)
  val it = () : unit

  ---

The datatype I set before：

---

```
datatype suit = Clubs | Diamonds | Hearts | Spades
datatype rank = Jack | Queen | King | Ace | Num of int 
type card = suit * rank

datatype color = Red | Black  (*spades  and  clubs  are  black,diamonds and hearts are red)*) 
datatype move = Discard of card | Draw 

exception IllegalMove
```

---

And I use the score function I create before， It can work correctly：

```
fun score (xs, score) =   
    let val sum = sum_cards(xs)
    in
       case (all_same_color(xs), sum > score) of
            (true, true) => (3 * (sum - score)) div 2
          | (true, false) => (score - sum) div 2
          | (false, true) => 3 * (sum - score)
          | (false, false) => score - sum
    end
```

Comment: Rename the `score` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I can use the variable **score** which is the score function.

Comment: Sorry, it is I can not use the variable score which is the score function.